# Laguerre diferential equation for the radial part of the Hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen

I am working on understanding the solution to the Schrödinger equation for the Hydrogen atom and I am now stuck on something concerning the Radial part of the equation.

After the change of variables $\rho = kr$ with $k^2 = - \frac{2 \mu E}{\hbar^2}$ and some work on the equations I got

$$\dfrac{d^2 u(\rho)}{d\rho^2} \rho + \left[ (2l+1) +1 - 2\rho \right] \frac{du(\rho)}{d\rho} + 2(n-l-1) u(\rho) = 0$$

I know that the solution to this equation is the Laguerre polynomial $u(\rho) = L_{n-l-1}^{2l+1}(2\rho)$. Aaccording to the equation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) the Laguerre polynomial is the solution to the following differential equation

$$ \frac{d^2 L_m^\alpha(x)}{dx^2} x + (\alpha+1-x)\frac{d L_m^\alpha(x)}{dx} + m L_m^\alpha(x) = 0 $$

I can identify that $m = n-l-1 $ and $\alpha = 2l+1$ but there is a slight difference in my equation (the factor $2$ in front of $n-l-1$ and $\rho$ that should be $2\rho$ in the first term of the equation). I am however confident that my equation is correct as it is the same as the one I found in some textbooks, and I would very much appreciate some explanation on my issue.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it

Comment: The usual substitution to get to this equation is $R_{nl} = \rho^l exp(-\rho/2) u(\rho)$. May be this substitution was not done as it should have been done.